# Using SammyJS with requireJS to route Modules

Tags: javascript, requirejs, sammy.js

Im just wondering if anyone has setup SammyJS with requireJS to route creation of modules depending on the provided hash address?

Is it possible? Advice?

Thanks

Comment: Did you ever get this working? @Raven

Comment: Hi @Niel. Yep, was a bunch of fiddling around with RequireJS and Javascript patterns but got there in the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [BoilerplateJS](http://boilerplatejs.org/) we have used crossroads.js to implement creation of modules depending on the provided hash address. This is the [router](https://github.com/ectechno/boilerplatejs/blob/master/src/core/helpers/router.js) which we use to implement that.

I believe sammyJS can be used in a similar manner.